# Reading a JSON file in R and Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class list

Tags: json, r, ggplot2

thanks in advance for any help can you give me. I  have two problems with a script  I am making in R.

I have this line of code:

```
train=rjson::fromJSON(file = "/home/felipe/Templates/Archivo de prueba/databritanica.json")
```

It works but only read the first line of the document, I need to read all the lines inside of document.   The output is of the command is list of 6 attributes of the  first row.   So how can I read the entire document to play with the data?

Example of the lines inside of the JSON file:

```
{
 "Month":"2014-05",
 "Longitude":-2.747770,
 "Latitude":53.389499,
 "Location":"On or near Cronton Road",
 "LSOA_name":"Halton 001B",
 "Crime_type":"Other theft"
}
```

So, I have the next issue.  When I try to implement the next code:

```
map<-get_map(location="united kingdom"  ,zoom=12,source="osm")

p <- ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(data=train, aes(x=X, y=Y, color=factor(LSOA_name)), alpha=0.05) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha=1.0, size=6.0),
                               title="Type of Crime")) +
  scale_colour_brewer(type="qual",palette="Paired") + 
  ggtitle("Top Crimes in Britain") +
  theme_light(base_size=20) +
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
ggsave("united kingdom_top_crimes_map.png", p, width=14, height=10, units="in")
```

This error appears:

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class list

How can fix the error? I need to mapping the data in the JSON files to map of UK.

**UPDATE**
 I fix the problem of reading the JSON file thanks too the user hrbrmstr,   i change the reading function rjson::fromJSON  to jsonlite::fromJSON.  Now my code is like this.

```
train=jsonlite::fromJSON("/home/felipe/Templates/Archivo de prueba/databritanica.json")
```

And changing the content of the JSON file
From this:

```
{
 "Month":"2014-05",
 "Longitude":-2.747770,
 "Latitude":53.389499,
 "Location":"On or near Cronton Road",
 "LSOA_name":"Halton 001B",
 "Crime_type":"Other theft"
}
  {
 "Month":"2014-05",
 "Longitude":-2.747770,
 "Latitude":53.389499,
 "Location":"On or near Cronton Road",
 "LSOA_name":"Halton 001B",
 "Crime_type":"Other theft"
}
```

to this

```
[
    {
     "Month":"2014-05",
     "Longitude":-2.747770,
     "Latitude":53.389499,
     "Location":"On or near Cronton Road",
     "LSOA_name":"Halton 001B",
     "Crime_type":"Other theft"
    },
    {
     "Month":"2014-05",
     "Longitude":-2.747770,
     "Latitude":53.389499,
     "Location":"On or near Cronton Road",
     "LSOA_name":"Halton 001B",
     "Crime_type":"Other theft"
    }   ]
```

But still I need to solve the problem of mapping.   Using the same code I show before now this error appears.

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'X' not found

Comment: ggplot2 only works with data frames. we'll need more of the file to see what `rjson`'s `fromJSON` is doing to the data, but you may want to switch to `jsonlite` as it tends to have saner conversion defaults. you can also try to transform `train` with `do.call(rbind, train)` but you really need to provide more data to really help.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I will try with jsonlite.   The rest script dont any more that I show the line that read de JSON file and the code that plot de map.   JSON file only have lines like show in the example.  The main point is to graph each type of crime in the map of UK

Comment: @hrbrmstr  change it to jsonlite and rewriting the JSON file content works  but still have the problem of plotting the map.